# paragraph inside a full height flexbox column with wrapping

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I tried to create a flexbox layout with sticky header and footer. Everything works fine until I turn on the flex-wrap: wrap mode and put a lot of long texts inside my container.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">head</div>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <p>very long text...</p> 
      <p>very long text...</p>
      <p>very long text...</p>
      <p>very long text...</p>
      <p>very long text...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  /* < REMOVE THIS AND EVERYTHING WORKS FINE */
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container > * {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.container > .main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRBzdo) example.

I need the auto-wrap ability because I would like to use this css for another parts where the column layout content should be wrapped horizontally.

BTW I'm very curious why this happens? Is there any 'official' explanation for this issue? Is it a known bug?

*Edit: I tested with Chrome v53.0.2785.143*

Comment: This is not the right way. Why don't use position: fixed? That's the appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGKmXY I created a possible layout that you can use. Check it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I looking for a full-flexbox solution. I can create a layout with the good-old fixed position but now I learning the flexbox technique so I would like to do only with that. If it won't be possible then ok. Just trying to understand why.

Comment: if that's the case. I think it is because of defined height.

Comment: Yes sure. If I removed the height - or just replace it with a min-height - it will works fine. What I don't really understand what happens when a flexbox with a column direction wraps its content. It looks like it thinks that there is unlimited horizontal space available - regardless if I set the width: 100%. Do you know why works like this?

Comment: @ggabor my question for you is why you want wrapping and can you show how you would like it to wrap?

Comment: @kukkuz: I want to wrap column contents because I tried to create a dead-simple flexbox grid solution. Just for learning and for fun :) So the wrap ability is one of the key part to build a solution. Now I think I will detach the wrap into a specific selector. Do you have a better idea?